# Not output as expected using Tumbling window 2 hours in Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Expected output of tumbling window 2 hours is 00:00 ,02:00, 04:00...
but output was 01:00, 03:00, 05:00...
Also for 6 hours window, expected output is 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00 but output was 03:00,09:00,15:00,21:00.
How to make it output as expected.
This is my query:

```
Select
GatewayId,
AVG(HumidityData) as DataValue
into Humidity120m
from input
group by TumblingWindow(hour,2),GatewayId


Select
GatewayId,
AVG(HumidityData) as DataValue
into Humidity360m
from input
group by TumblingWindow(hour,6),GatewayId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. Tumbling window is partitioning the timeline by itself. More details, you can refer to this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/tumbling-window-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).